# How to make a call to users graph API from Azure Devops Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

The following works for me for Azure Devops Services (cloud):

```
curl ... https://vssps.dev.azure.com/acme/_apis/graph/users
```

However, for my on-premise installation I'm getting 404 for all following options:

```
curl ... https://tfs.acme.com/_apis/graph/users
curl ... https://vssps.tfs.acme.com/_apis/graph/users
curl ... https://tfs.acme.com/test-collection/_apis/graph/users
```

I know its not credentials issue since I manage to make other api calls successfully.

I could not find any documentation for on-prem. Cloud version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Its seems it just may not be supported at all. For now I'm using `identites` api, but would love to make this work instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This API doesn't support yet Azure DevOps Server:

[image]